# Meteor: How to add Nodes.js library (not package) in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I am trying to integrate [ziggeo](http://ziggeo.com/docs#server-integration) sdk into meteor but couldn't able to it. Does someone have experience or know how to integrate **`ziggeo`**
 in meteor. It provide a node.js sdk for server integration. I tried using [meteorhacks/npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) but still not able to do it. I know it is used for **npm** packages. But if i uninstall this package it gave following error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'npmRequire'

If i install [meteorhacks/npm](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) it gave following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './ziggeo/ziggeo-sdk.min.js'

Below is code i am using for server integration:

```
ZiggeoSdk = Meteor.npmRequire('./ziggeo/ziggeo-sdk.min.js');
ZiggeoSdk.init('86381021416de9dcb1c04c74195bc5ee', '54d16056f809ee8c5f715ac7a03d8374', 'ecd3fdc60ac0318642301713d8758e1c');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: how about telling us what is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: @MarkUretsky I have added code. Thanks man.

Comment: I think what @MarkUretsky meant was how exactly you were trying to use `meteorhacks/npm` package. This should have worked.

Comment: @MohsinRafi now that we see the code it's ovious what's wrong you don't use `meteorhacks:npm` and also this isn't an `https://www.npmjs.com` package you can't find it over there so you will have to create local global npm package before you can use it

Comment: Please read the documentation. `require` doesn't exist. If you use mrt:npm then you can try `Meteor.npmRequire` instead. Besides, require/npmRequire is for npm packages, not for .js files. There is a million and one answers on stackoverflow on how to use good-old javascript libraries in meteor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load javascript library into Meteor app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514303/unable-to-load-javascript-library-into-meteor-app)

Comment: I already did. See the close-vote.

Comment: @ChristianFritz Sorry man.